# extract input data from ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know I can extract the data I plot in a `ggplot2` plot using

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
ggplot_build(p)$data
```

But `data` in this case is the data being plotted. Is there any way of getting the input data -- `df` in this case -- back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p` itself is a `list`, you can get `df` with `p$data`.

A samll example:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_point()
identical(p$data, mtcars)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

The same approach but wrapped in a package/function is to 'capture the spirit of your `ggplot` calls' using [`library(ggghost)`](https://github.com/jonocarroll/ggghost)

```
library(ggghost)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = 1:20, z= letters[1:20])

p %g<% ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y))
p <- p + geom_point()

rm(df)
ggghost::recover_data(p)
## this returns the data back to your environment
```